# Python Label not updating?

Tags: python, tkinter

My label is not being updated in python for some reason when i enter details into to the entry box it should update it. Thanks for the help

```
import tkinter
gui = tkinter.Tk()

num1e = tkinter.IntVar()
num2e = tkinter.IntVar()
num3e = tkinter.IntVar()
num4e = tkinter.IntVar()
num5e = tkinter.IntVar()
num6e = tkinter.IntVar()
num7e = tkinter.IntVar()

numout = tkinter.IntVar()

def Find():
    numout.set = num1e

gui.geometry("450x450+500+300")

num1 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num1e).pack()
num2 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num2e).pack()
num3 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num3e).pack()
num4 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num4e).pack()
num5 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num5e).pack()
num6 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num6e).pack()
num7 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num7e).pack()

label = tkinter.Label(gui, textvariable = numout).pack()

Sb = tkinter.Button(gui, text ="Find 8th", command = Find).pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of an `IntVar` or `StringVar` you must call the `set` method and give the new value as a parameter. To get the value *from* one of these variables you must call the `get` method.

For example, to set it to the value that is in the `num1` entry widget you would do this:

```
numout.set(num1e.get())
```

Note that unless you're using variable tracing, using all of the `IntVar`s is unnecessary -- you can directly set and get the values from entry widgets and labels (assuming you properly save a reference to the widgets):

```
num1 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num1e)
num2 = tkinter.Entry(...)
...
label = tkinter.Label(...)
num1.pack()
num2.pack()
...
label.pack()
...
num1_value = num1.get()
label.configure(text=num1_value)
```